# FB.getLoginStatus is not returning correct status when third party cookies are disabled in chrome

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies

We are getting very strange issue , in case if we disable third party cookies, our observation is for loggedin user Facebook FB.getLoginStatus API returns wrong status as "unknown" i.e. "not logged in" status however when our user clicks on FB login button the API for login ( FB.login) is invoked this API returns correct status i.e. 'connected" which means "user is already logged in"

but again when we call FB.getLoginStatus to check login status in other pages of our website it shows us wrong status which results in navigating our user to login page always.

You can use following steps on Chrome browser to reproduce this issue and check output of both the API's

- Go to Settings scroll down to Privacy
- Open Content Settings pop up
- Turn ON "Block third-party cookies and site data",
- You can keep"Allow local data to be set (recommended)" opted.

Empty/Clear all the saved data from "Exception" and"All Cookies and site data"
After following these steps our website snapviz would not work. To make it work just turn off "Block third-party cookies and site data"

Can someone guide us in research on internal difference of these API's. Or what can be the best way to handle third party cookie blocking scenario in Chrome.

Thanks 
Rashmi

Answer (score 1):

I did not go through the API, but when faced the similar issue on integration open-graph api I have reported it on facebook bugs and started using PHP SDK instead. You can start using Facebook PHP SDK instead of the Facebook JS SDK until it gets resolved.